# Why does IPython.display.display render outputs in different order if specified as a list?

Tags: pandas, ipython, jupyter

```
def inspect_df(df):
    results = (df.head(), df.tail(), df.info(), df.describe(include='all'),)
    for result in results:
        display(result)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]})

inspect_df(df)
```

Note that `df.info()` is the third item in results. Yet, this renders the output of info first, then the rest of the items. How can I get it to print the outputs in specified order?

[image: order with list]

But instead, if I explicitly call the display (without the list), it renders correctly:

```
def inspect_df(df):
    display(df.head())
    display(df.tail())
    display(df.info())
    display(df.describe(include='all'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]})

inspect_df(df)
```

[image: order without list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `df.info()` doesnot return anything apart from printing the info, a workaround would be saving the info information as a string and then save them in `results` to iterate;

```
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
info_string = buffer.getvalue()

def inspect_df(df):
    results = (df.head(), df.tail(), info_string , df.describe(include='all'),)
    for result in results:
        print(result)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]})

inspect_df(df)
```

---

```
   x  y
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
   x  y
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
x    3 non-null int64
y    3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 176.0 bytes

         x    y
count  3.0  3.0
mean   2.0  5.0
std    1.0  1.0
min    1.0  4.0
25%    1.5  4.5
50%    2.0  5.0
75%    2.5  5.5
max    3.0  6.0
```